# How to animate a line from start to stop

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm drawing a list of line on Mapbox using LineLayer from GeoJson file:

```
try {
        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("source", loadJsonFromRaw());
        mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource);

        LineLayer lineLayer = new LineLayer("line-layer", "source");
        lineLayer.setProperties(
                PropertyFactory.lineWidth(1f),
                PropertyFactory.lineColor(Color.RED)
        );

        mapboxMap.addLayer(lineLayer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Everything is ok, the lines could be drawn. But now, I want to animate the lines from start point to end point of each line when MapBox renders them. From [MapBox doc](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/map-sdk/overview/runtime-styling/#sources):

> A benefit of having your data inside a GeoJSON source is that you can
>   update, remove, or add additional features inside the source at any
>   time, providing a solution to animating data in your map through the
>   Runtime Styling API. For example, using an Android ValueAnimator, you
>   can move a feature by updating its coordinates within the GeoJSON
>   data.

But I don't know how to do it, tried to search on internet and SO but got nothing, does anyone know how to do it? Thanks.